# GTab with access denied to all app databases

Tags: applications, sqlite

I have a brand new GTAB (Android) that was working fine but suddenly, give a reboot while I was using *anMoney*, a very good application of financial organization.

Until anything I'd like to observe that I have plenty of space in NAND Flash storage memory, something about 100 MB. This storage is used to keep app's databases under `/data` directory. I'd like to observe that my ROM is original and android version is 2.2.

So after reboot, all applications that effectively use SQLite stopped to work. Each one gives substantial logs, pointing me that this problem are involving not so exclusive SQLite:

## App1: anMoney

```
E/ApplicationContext( 1933): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml.bak
E/ApplicationContext( 1933): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml.bak
I/Database( 1933): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
E/Database( 1933): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/databases/My Book", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933): com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.database.az: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.database.sql.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.database.sql.s.a(Unknown Source)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.app.book.a.t.b(Unknown Source)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.app.book.a.t.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):     ... 10 more
```

## App 2: Battery Widget

```
E/ApplicationContext( 2674): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/com.elvison.batterywidget_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/com.elvison.batterywidget_preferences.xml.bak
E/ApplicationContext( 2674): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/_has_set_default_values.xml to backup file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/_has_set_default_values.xml.bak
I/Database( 2674): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
E/Database( 2674): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/databases/alarms.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
```

## App 3: Meridian

```
E/Database( 3110): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/org.iii.romulus.meridian/databases/webviewCache.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
W/ApplicationContext( 3110): Attempt to read preferences file /data/data/org.iii.romulus.meridian/shared_prefs/google_ads.xml.xml without permission
I/Database( 3110): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
E/Database( 3110): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/org.iii.romulus.meridian/databases/google_analytics.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110): Couldn't open google_analytics.db for writing (will try read-only):
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PersistentEventStore.getNumStoredEvents(Unknown Source)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PersistentEventStore.startNewVisit(Unknown Source)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.start(Unknown Source)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.start(Unknown Source)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.start(Unknown Source)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at org.iii.romulus.meridian.core.Utils.startTracker(Utils.java:440)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at org.iii.romulus.meridian.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:82)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at org.iii.romulus.meridian.MainActivity.initViews(MainActivity.java:292)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at org.iii.romulus.meridian.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:150)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/SQLiteOpenHelper( 3110):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To turn things more intriguing, I bought an Andoid app called *SQLite Editor* and open the 3 individual databases given above. All 3 are intact, without presenting data loss or corruption.

What can be wrong? Any one can point me what is happening?